# Django model foreign key to Superuser

Tags: python, django, model

I have a django model Request which has a field Approver which is set to the User which has the superuser status. I would like to assign value to this field automatically such that it rotates among the project admins. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: You could use the id of your model instance and divide by the amount of your superusers use % to get remainder to choose one.

Comment: I think we might need a bit more of an idea what this looks like. What could be done is to assign it to the admin with the fewest requests assigned to them. But overall the question needs much more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function in the Admin form which sets the approver to the User which has the least ammount of requests. Works fine for me.

```
def get_recipient(self):

    approvers = User.objects.annotate(num_of_requests=models.Count('model_field_related_name')).order_by('num_of_requests')
    return approvers.first()
```

Answer (score 1):

A easy solution that comes to my mind is just in the html template that uses the request model, you can do a function that evaluates a possible asigned user.. something like that: 
 1. Add a field in your request model that is a foreign key to your user model
 Example:

```
class Request(models.Model):
some other code...
    assigned_user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And add an asigned boolean in your User Model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    assigned=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

2. Then in your html code for creating a request:

You can do something like:

```
{% for user in Users %}
    {% if user.isAdmin %}
        {% if not user.assigned %}
            <input name="request.varName">{{User.id}}</input>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Remember that in your view you have to call the request model and your Users model.. You can achieve this in this way:

```
class RequestCreate(CreateView):
    ... some other code..
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(RequestCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['Users'] = User.objects.all()
            #context['venue_list'] = Venue.objects.all()
            #context['festival_list'] = Festival.objects.all()
            # And so on for more models
    return context
```

I hope to be usefull here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as defaults. Define a function like so

```
def default_func():
    last_assigned = Request.objects.latest().Approver # gets latest assigned Approver
    # the below if statement always looks for the next superuser pk
    if User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True, pk__gt=last_assigned.pk).exists():
        next_assigned_superuser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True, pk__gt=last_assigned.pk)\
            .order_by('pk')[0]
    # if there isn't a superuser with a higher pk than the last_assigned_superuser, it will choose
    # the superuser below or equal to it with the lowest pk. This will handle the case where there is
    # only one superuser without any fuss.
    else:
        next_assigned_superuser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True, pk__lte=last_assigned.pk) \
            .order_by('pk')[0]

    return next_assigned_superuser
```

and add this to your Approver field:

```
# you must pass the function without parenthesis at the end, or else it will
# set the default to whatever the value is at server run time. 
# If you pass the function itself, it will be evaluated every time a 
# default is needed.
Approver = models.ForeignKey(User, default=default_func)
```

Edit: Added a return value to default_func. Whoops.